# Error while installing notebook using pip

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip, jupyter-notebook

note: I am on linux(ubuntu,mint)

I am trying to install jupyter. But after some searching I realised that the error I have when trying to install jupyter is due to notebook.

So here is the error I have when trying to install notebook using `sudo pip install notebook`.

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-EKmj0F/scandir/setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-OB5xPr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EKmj0F/scandir/
```

If you want [here](https://pastebin.com/GTWXsNDx) is the whole output of `pip install notebook`.

Thank for answers in advance.

This is the relevant part of the error message:

```
_scandir.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Python headers:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Your installation process tries to compile an extension with `gcc` and you seem to be missing the necessary decencies.

Comment: Nice. Hope it will help next person search for this.